# Why does my command prompt and PowerShell only open the file, not executing it?

Tags: python, cmd, token

My command prompt can't find the executable that I ask it to launch.

```
C:\Users\NabihBawazir\...\aws-token\aws-token>./token.sh
```

This is the script:

```
C:\Users\NabihBawazir\...\aws-token\aws-token>python python_script.py
```

The error is it is only opening the file in Visual Studio, not executing the script.

Comment: What error do you get exactly ?

Comment: The error is only open file in visual studio not execute the script

Comment: You need to tell the shell which program to use, e.g. `python myScript.py`. Otherwise Windows will use the default program for that file extension (the one that opens when you doubleclick such a file).

Comment: uhm - did you just include the prompt in your question for demonstration purposes or did you actually type it with your command?

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, it is confusing and unclear.

Comment: Re *"This is the script:"*: What do you mean? It *seems* like a dump from a command line window: A prompt (output from the shell) + some input

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to open a .sh file which is a shell script which neither cmd or PowerShell can open, unless you are running this on WSL which it doesn't look like you are.

You either need to rename the token.sh to token.bat, or even .ps1 so that you can run it on windows

Comment: If the .sh file includes more inside then what you have shown, you may also need to do a bit of translation from Linux shell to Windows batch